# Why default credentials are not passing to proxy server in HttpWebrequest which has access to proxy server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, proxy

We have implemented the proxy server for calling the third party website which is currently happening through firewall rule. We have added the Service account to Proxy server ,URL is whitelisted and IE browser has the Proxy set up.

Whenever we are calling the third party website , we are getting the 407 Authentication from proxy server and application running by Service account identity.

Is there anything like Microsoft is not allowing to pass the credentials to the proxy server ?

*Application deployed in IIS 10
*Asp.net web form
*Windows server 2016

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: issue is happening in asp.net web form application which is deployed in IIS. So c# developer might have knowledge on this

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error 407 proxy authentication required, you can try to define a proxy class first, then set the Credentials property of the proxy object, and finally assign the defined proxy object to the Proxy proxy property of the Web Service object.

```
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

        HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest();
        request.Proxy = proxy;
```